# 6 dice yahtzee straight and fullhouse problems

Tags: c#, logic

I have made a 5 dice yahtzee game, and i am trying to make it work for 6 dice aswell, can you help this two functions more universal my code as of this moment :)

i have prepared dice values in list `int[] i` 
and I have detected fullHouse with this very simple method:

```
 Array.Sort(i);

 if( ((i[0] == i[1]) && (i[1] == i[2]) && (i[3] == i[4]))
  {
    ... sum it up
  }
 else if((i[0] == i[1]) && (i[2] == i[3]) && (i[3] == i[4]))
  {
     ... sum it up
  }
```

I have detected straight with this very simple method

```
 Array.Sort(i);

  if( ((i[0] == 1) &&
       (i[1] == 2) &&
       (i[2] == 3) &&
       (i[3] == 4) &&
       (i[4] == 5)) ||
      ((i[0] == 2) &&
       (i[1] == 3) &&
       (i[2] == 4) &&
       (i[3] == 5) &&
       (i[4] == 6)) )
  {
    ... sum it up
  }
```

Thx in advance

Comment: I created a logic for poker a while ago and used linq for full house: Find the number with the highest frequency and make sure there are 3. Then find the number with the highest frequency other than the number before and make sure there are 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the logic completely manually like that produces code that is unwieldy and hard to extend. Abstracting things a little with LINQ will help a lot.

To detect a full house, group rolls by value and check the cardinality of each group (I am using `i` as the array of rolls to follow the original code, but that's a bad name for an array):

```
var groups = i.GroupBy(i => i);
```

Then you can check for a full house very easily:

```
var hasFullHouse = groups.Any(g1 => 
    g1.Count >= 3 && groups.Except(g1).Any(g2 => g2.Count >= 2)
);
```

> "If there is any group with at least 3 dice and there is also a
>   different group with at least 2 dice, you have a full house."

To check for a straight, iterate over the groups in order. For each one, check if the group representing the previous die roll exists. If it does increment a counter, otherwise reset the counter. If the counter ever reaches 5 there is a straight:

```
var runLength = 0;
var map = groups.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count);
foreach (var roll in map.Keys.OrderBy(k => k))
{
    var runLength = map.Contains(roll - 1) ? runLength + 1 : 0;
    if (runLength == 5)
    {
        // straight detected
    }
}
```

Both of these methods will work regardless of the number of dice in the game.

Answer (score 1):

if you have list of ints you can check if they are consecutive values (straight)

```
bool isfullhouse = !list.Select((i,j) => i-j).Distinct().Skip(1).Any();
return isfullhouse;
```

you can make your array a list by:

```
var list = yourArray.ToList();
```

second one can be modified to look like:

```
var list = yourArray.ToList().Skip(2);
if(yourArray[0]==yourArray[1]) // checks XX
{
    var distincted = list.Distinct(); 
    if(distincted.Count()==1) // checks if other values are equal
    {
       if(distincted[0]!=yourArray[0]) // checks if not XXXXXX
             return true; 
    }
}
return false;
```

it will check if there is a full house like XX YYYY (it can have any number of Y's)